# CKEditor copy/paste images uploading but not showing in editor

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, ckeditor

I tried custom uploader for CKEditor and it is working fine if we upload images via button of default file manager of CKEditor but when i copy and paste images from Word images are uploaded but does show up in editor

here is my code for upload

```
 function ck_upload()
        {


        $upload_dir = array(
            'img'=> '/GeneralUploads/ckUploads',
        );

        $imgset = array(
            // 'maxsize' => 2000,    
            // 'maxwidth' => 900,    
            // 'maxheight' => 800,    
            'minwidth' => 10,      
            'minheight' => 10,
            'type' => array('bmp', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'),
        );

        // If 0, will OVERWRITE the existing file
        define('RENAME_F', 1);

        $re = '';
        if(isset($_FILES['upload']) && strlen($_FILES['upload']['name']) >1) {
            define('F_NAME', preg_replace('/\.(.+?)$/i', '', basename($_FILES['upload']['name'])));  //get filename without extension

            // get protocol and host name to send the absolute image path to CKEditor    
            $site = 'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
            $sepext = explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['upload']['name']));
            $type = end($sepext);    // gets extension
            $upload_dir = in_array($type, $imgset['type']) ? $upload_dir['img'] : $upload_dir['audio'];
            $upload_dir = trim($upload_dir, '/') .'/';

            //checkings for image or audio
            if(in_array($type, $imgset['type'])){
                // list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);  // image width and height
                if(isset($width) && isset($height)) {
                    if($width > $imgset['maxwidth'] || $height > $imgset['maxheight']) $re .= '\\n Width x Height = '. $width .' x '. $height .' \\n The maximum Width x Height must be: '. $imgset['maxwidth']. ' x '. $imgset['maxheight'];
                    if($width < $imgset['minwidth'] || $height < $imgset['minheight']) $re .= '\\n Width x Height = '. $width .' x '. $height .'\\n The minimum Width x Height must be: '. $imgset['minwidth']. ' x '. $imgset['minheight'];
                    if($_FILES['upload']['size'] > $imgset['maxsize']*1000) $re .= '\\n Maximum file size must be: '. $imgset['maxsize']. ' KB.';
                }
            }

            else $re .= 'The file: '. $_FILES['upload']['name']. ' has not the allowed extension type.';

            //set filename; if file exists, and RENAME_F is 1, set "img_name_I"
            // $p = dir-path, $fn=filename to check, $ex=extension $i=index to rename
            function setFName($p, $fn, $ex, $i){
                if(RENAME_F ==1 && file_exists($p .$fn .$ex)) return setFName($p, F_NAME .'_'. ($i +1), $ex, ($i +1));
                else return $fn .$ex;
            }

            $f_name = setFName($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/'. $upload_dir, F_NAME, ".$type", 0);
            $uploadpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/'. $upload_dir . $f_name;  // full file path

            // If no errors, upload the image, else, output the errors
            if($re == '') {
                // print_r($_FILES);exit;
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $uploadpath)) {

                    $CKEditorFuncNum = $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'];

                      $url = $site. $upload_dir . $f_name;
                    $msg = F_NAME .'.'. $type .' successfully uploaded: \\n- Size: '. number_format($_FILES['upload']['size']/1024, 2, '.', '') .' KB';
                    $re = in_array($type, $imgset['type']) ? "window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($CKEditorFuncNum, '$url', '$msg')"  //for img

                   : 'var cke_ob = window.parent.CKEDITOR; for(var ckid in cke_ob.instances) { if(cke_ob.instances[ckid].focusManager.hasFocus) break;} cke_ob.instances[ckid].insertHtml(\'<audio src="'. $url .'" controls></audio>\', \'unfiltered_html\'); alert("'. $msg .'"); var dialog = cke_ob.dialog.getCurrent();  dialog.hide();';
                    print_r($re);
                }
                else $re = 'alert("Unable to upload the file")';
            }
            else $re = 'alert("'. $re .'")';
        }

        @header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        echo '<script>'. $re .';</script>';
}
```

}

This function is working fine when I browse image from local and upload to server but when I copy images and equations from Word it uploads as image but in editor there is nothing. I checked in network status in console and it says

> CKEditorFuncNum is undefined index in $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum']

Comment: Please check which CKEditor version you use because when you copy paste (not drag & drop) image from Word using Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V, the image should either be uploaded or converted into base64 string if there is no uploader. This feature was introduced in CKEditor 4.8.0

Comment: My ckeditor version is 4.9.2 ..images uploads but does appear in editor after upload. It gives the error "Incorrect Server Response"